# Found conflict between different versions of the same dependent assembly in Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Got the following warning message when compiling:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.4.1/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5): Warning MSB3276: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects" property to true in the project file. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=294190. (MSB3276) (mobile.iOS)
```

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac version 7.3.3 (build 23) and Xamarin.

When I look the the detailed build output, I can see the following lines :

```
Target ResolveAssemblyReferences:
    Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Net.Http, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" from Version "1.5.0.0" [/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.4.1/lib/mono/gac/System.Net.Http/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Net.Http.dll] to Version "4.0.0.0" [/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/System.Net.Http.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.4.1/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2003,5): warning MSB3276: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects" property to true in the project file. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=294190.
```

I know warnings are not errors, but I'd like to solve it anyway, cause it can't be a good thing.

Comment: Check your project references and make sure that you have an explicit reference to `System.Net.Http` from the `Xamarin.iOS` package (and not one from the Mono GAC)

Comment: System.Net.Http and Xamarin.iOS are referenced.

Comment: The other references are System, System.Core, System.IO.Compression, System.Xml, System.Xml.Linq. 

Then there are a bunch that comes from packages : Newtonsoft.Json, Plugin.Connectivity, Plugin.Connectivite.Abstractions, Plugin.SecurityStorage, Plugin.SecurityStorage.Abstractions, Plugin.Settings, Plugin.Settings.Abstractions, System.Net.Http.Extensions, System.New. Http.Primitives, Xamarin.Forms.Core, Xamarin.Forms.Platform, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS, Xamarin.Forms.Xmal.

Comment: I have the same problem in Xamarin.Android (XF PCL Project)... have someone find a solution?

Comment: In my case, I think it is because I'm using two packages that are using different assembly of the same library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I think it is because I'm using two packages that are using different assembly of the same library.